# Fit a throttle to a pedal assist.bike?

Tags: pedals, electric-bike

Can I fit a throttle to a pedal assist Viking Gravity ebike?

If yes what is needed other than a throttle?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Aside - some countries in the world require that the bike have pedal assist and disallow throttles.  Depending on where you are, a throttle-based ebike may be illegal, or may need to be registered/insured as an electric motorbike.   Check before you go too far.

Answer (score 4):

It's going to depend on several things:

- The controller
- The type of pedal-assist detection
- How good you are with electronics
- Whether you can get a full kit *for that model*

If you can't get a suitable kit, you either need to be good at electronics (design and assembly), or pay someone who is.

I've sketched out a design in the past (on paper - I don't have them any more).  Here it is, with some other options.

- One plausible and not too invasive idea involves faking the input to the pedal sensor with a throttle that gives pulses at a suitable rate.  This is what a former colleague was going to do after discussions, but analysing and generating electronic signals is the sort of thing we both do for a living.
- Replacing all the controls and motor drive circuit may be an option, but how could you be sure the new bits would fit and be compatible with the motor and battery? Is the charging controller integrated into the same module?
- The existing control circuit may have an unused throttle input (throttles are popular where they're allowed so it's not unlikely.  It may be very easy to interface or very tricky, depending on how much is present.

Comment: It's meant to be more about the questions than the users! Look out for answers from people with high reputation scores and you won't go wrong. The [ebike tag](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric-bike?tab=Newest) has quite a lot that might be of interest, though we don't have many e-bike tinkerers here.  I no longer have access to one, and besides, different manufacturers do different things